# How to add vDOM elements using React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to dynamically add some elements using react-native. I've followed the (sparse) docs and have come up with this:

```
var root = <Text/>;
React.render(root, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This throws an error: **You cannot render into anything but a top root**. I asked about this in #reactnative and they said to make sure root was only returning a single node, which it is but I still can't get around the error.

Answer (score 1):

`AppRegistry` is the JS entry point to running all React Native apps. App root components should register themselves with `AppRegistry.registerComponent`, then the native system can load the bundle for the app.

So, you should render this something like this, where `Root` is a top level  component in your app.-

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Root', () => Root);
```

For more Info-
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html#content